# How to push data without hardcoding the name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, push

I want to build an JSON with name and value like name:"john".

This is my code:

```
var allFields = [];
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++){

        name = inputs[i].name;
        item = inputs[i].value;
        allFields.push({name: item});
}
var alleFelder = JSON.stringify(allFields);
alert(alleFelder);
```

My problem is that "name" gets hardcorded into the JSON.

So instead of...:
name:"john",
lastname:"brooks",
birthdate:"1.1.1999"

...im getting:
name:"john",
name:"brooks",
name:"1.1.1999"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274327/14357

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this simple function to add new keys with values to your object

```js
const myObj = {}


function addKeyVal(obj, k, v){
  obj[k] = v;
}

const keys = ["name", "bday"];
const values = ["Jhon", "1-1-2020"];



for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)addKeyVal(myObj, keys[i], values[i])

console.log(myObj)
```